# Ruby on Rails ActiveResource not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, activeresource

I am new to RoR and I am trying to build simple web application that uses ActiveResource ActiveRecord

I have one simple rails project hosted on localhost:3001. The application has welcome controller that looks like this

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @persons = []
    num = 0
    until num < 10 do
      @persons[num] = Person.new
      @persons[num].name = [*('A'..'Z')].sample(8).join
      @persons[num].surname = [*('A'..'Z')].sample(64).join 
      @persons[num].dob = Time.at(rand * Time.now.to_i)      
      num+1      
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      format.xml { render :xml => @persons}
    end
  end
end
```

Person class looks like this:

```
class Person
  attr_accessor :name, :surname, :dob
end
```

This rails application should use as REST service for other application hosted on localhost:3000

The model in letter application looks like this:

```
class Person < ActiveResource::Base
   self.site = "http://localhost:3001"
end
```

Now, my question is how to list all 10 persons on the view?

I have tried to use Person model as ActiveResource, in person controller:

```
class PersonController < ApplicationController
  def index
   @persons= Person.find(":all")   
  end
end
```

by I get message ActiveResource::ResourceNotFound in PersonController#index

Thanks in advance.

Comment: ActiveResource was recently removed from the Rails project.  You may want to look into alternatives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I'm not sure why you're trying to create 10 People in your WelcomeController, but here's a better way.

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    10.times do
      person = Person.new
      person.name = [*('A'..'Z')].sample(8).join
      person.surname = [*('A'..'Z')].sample(64).join
      person.dob = Time.at(rand * Time.now.to_i) 
      person.save # This part is necessary for data to persist between requests
    end

    @persons = Person.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.xml { render :xml => @persons}
    end
  end
end
```

Then, of course in your PersonController you can use

```
@persons = Person.all
```

or

```
@persons = Person.find(:all)
```

Comment: WelcomeController was just handy because it is suggested in confi/routes.rb  thanks a lot I will immediately try this.

Comment: I am getting ArgumentError at line  person.save

Comment: Well then something else is going on with your code, but saying "I am getting ArgumentError" doesn't help much.

Comment: He is using ActiveResource, not ActiveRecord.